# How does one work out hashrate based on number of submitted shares

Tags: mining-pools

We are running a pool and are trying to get a total hashrate estimate.  How can we figure out how many hashes are being submitted to the pool based on the shares submitted?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/what-is-the-correct-algorithm-to-calculate-worker-pool-hashrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A share has more often than not the maximum Target value (as in Difficulty 1). To create a share one needs [on average 2^32 tries](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8814/323), or hashes. Multiply the number of submitted shares by 2^32, divide over the period those shares were submitted in and you have your hashrate estimate.